# Como posso passar um parâmetro, de qualquer tipo, para um vetor genérico? - C

Tags: c, parâmetros, genéricos

Eu tenho uma estrutura do tipo `TTabelaX`, que basicamente é uma tabela que vou armazenar elementos de qualquer tipo, ou seja, eu posso criar uma tabela para armazenar um elemento tipo `TCarro`, com placa e cor, depois posso utilizar a mesma estrutura para criar uma tabela para armazenar um tipo `TPessoa`, com nome e cpf.

Em outras palavras, é uma estrutura genérica para criar uma tabela de qualquer coisa.

**Meu problema** está na parte de inserir o elemento, como vou dizer pra função `inserir()` que estou passando um elemento que pode ser de qualquer tipo?

```
typedef struct tabelax TTabelaX;
struct tabelax{
    int max;
    int pos;
    void** tabela;
};

TTabelaX*cria_tabela(int tam){
    // Aloquei a estrutura e passei o endereço pra aux
    TTabelaX* aux = (TTabelaX*)malloc(sizeof(TTabelaX));
    // Tabela aponta p/ um vetor do tipo void*, tornando genérico
    aux->tabela = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * tam);
    aux->max = tam;
    aux->pos = 0;    
    return aux;
}

void inserir(TTabelaX* aux, ???){//<--como passar um parâmetro sem saber seu tipo?
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ponteiro para void.

```
TTabelaX*cria_tabela(int tam) {

  // Aloquei a estrutura e passei o endereço pra aux
  TTabelaX* aux = (TTabelaX*)malloc(sizeof(TTabelaX));

  // Tabela aponta p/ um vetor do tipo void*, tornando genérico
  aux->tabela = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * tam);
  memset(aux->tabela, 0, sizeof(void*) * tam); // <------- inicializar os ponteiros
  aux->max = tam;
  aux->pos = 0;    
  return aux;
}

void inserir(TTabelaX* aux, void* pX) { // <-- declare como um ponteiro para void
  ...
}
```

Comment: Show! Agora deu certo. Uma dúvida, porque deve-se inicializar com o comando memset? Seria por segurança ou porque é uma boa prática?

Comment: é preciso inicializar os ponteiros, senão eles vão ter valores "lixo" (o que já estava na memória naquelas posções) e vão apontar para endereços de memória inválidos

Answer (score 0):

Você pode declarar o elemento como string (caso seja c++) ou como um vetor char. Ambos aceitam valores de qualquer tipo.